# How to properly graph A(x) when evaluating definite integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I came across this problem: $$A(x)=\int^x_1f(t)dt. \textrm {Graph }  y=A(x) \textrm { for }1\leq x \leq 5\textrm { when }f(t)=6-t.$$ 
I know the integral would be $\int^x_1 (6-t)dx$, but how would I graph it not knowing the value of x? Is the only way to do this by guessing a value of x?

I got the integral equaling $6x - 6 - \frac12x^2 - \frac12 = - \frac12x^2 +6x -6.5 $. If this was done correctly, is this how I get to my answer?

Really, this came with an  [answer key which showed the graph this way,[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh2Ot.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh2Ot.png) but I don't understand how they got that value of $x$.

Comment: It clearly says graph the function $A(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2}+6x-6.5$ for $1\le x\le 5$. I don't see any problem doing this. Are you sure that picture is the answer key to this exercise?

Comment: Ah, I see. I was looking at the problem wrong.

Comment: I know this may be very basic, but why did you put$-x^2$ over $2$?

Comment: No reason at all. That's just the way I like writing all my fractions.

Comment: I just plugged that in, and I did not get 1 and 3.75 like the graph would suggest I would. The values I got were $-1$ and 11.

Comment: What exactly did you plug in?

Comment: I plugged in 1 and 5 into $-\frac{x^2}{2}+6x-6.5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing things there. $A(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2}+6x-6.5$ is a so-called area function. It represents the amount of net area under the graph of the line $y=6-t$ between $1$ and any value of $x$. For example, if $x$ is 2, then the net area under the graph of $y=6-t$ between $1$ to $2$ would be $A(2)=3.5$ square units. If $x=5$, then the net area between $1$ and $5$ would be $A(5)=11$ square units. Anyway, the answer should be the graph of $A(x)=-\frac{x^2}{2}+6x-6.5$. This is a simple quadratic. It's not that hard to graph it.

Comment: Thank you. Just one question: Why in the graph does it graph the line at $x$ at around $3.75$ and not $5$?

Comment: I don't think there is any particular reason to that. That's just the way they decided to draw that dotted line. $1$ and $5$ is the domain they want you to graph $A(x)$. It has noting to do with the line $y=6-t$ itself.

Comment: Do you see that yellow area under $y=6-t$? Its numerical value (how much of that yellow area is shaded out) is equivalent to what you get when you plug in $3.75$ into the function $A(x)$.

Comment: So they just chose 3.75 as the value for $x$?

Comment: It looks like it. Yes.